# Flutter:App not installed on android real device

Tags: flutter

I am getting

> App not installed

on an Android real device through direct apk installation. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you already have previous version of the app installed on your phone?

Comment: i dont have previoius version as it not installed

Comment: What's the issue or error showing in the logcat?

Comment: I sent to my client copy of apk through google drive. It is not installed and it show this error to them sunny

Comment: check with another device, I thought your device has no enough storage space for app.